# jQuery how to remove :selected attribute and add new one properly

Tags: jquery

How do I remove `:selected` attribute and add new one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're talking about a `<select>` just set the value using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) like this:

```
$('#mySelect').val('new value');
```

This automatically selects the `<option>` with that value.

Comment: $('#slot').find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
$('#slot').val('0');

Thanks this works for me. Strange, but val() doesn't remove attr selected from previous option.

Comment: @Beck - Is it a `<select multiple>`? Just `.val()` won't remove it...that's for getting the current value, `.val('new value')` changes it, but `.val()` with no params doesn't have any *setting* effect.

Comment: No it's not multiple, simple select box.

Answer (score 45):

You want something like

```
$('#mySelect option:selected').removeAttr('selected');

$('#mySelect option:nth-child(5)').attr('selected','selected');//select the one you want
```

*btw*, are you talking about a select list single (e.g. dropdown)?... or a select multiple? - you'll need to adjust accordingly if this is a multi-select.

*I updated the [nth child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)... when setting the selected attribute as square bracket notation [4] doesn't work in the selector.*

Comment: This only answers the first half of the question :)

Comment: That's an incredibly long way to do what `.val()` does, and doesn't even allow you to select by value...which is almost always what you want :)

Comment: I guess it all depends what info you have handy.  I've also had a scenario where I have multiple options with the same value, but different labels (e.g. you are picking a person, but under the covers selecting a department) does .val() work on a select if you pass either the value of the value attribute or the option text?

Comment: @scunliffe - It doesn't select on text, not anymore anyway, this used to be the case. For that you'd pass a function into `.val()`, or do a selector based on text.

Comment: .val() will not work if you are saving the state of the DOM for later use.  Unless you remove the attribute, and add it back, such as scunliffe has done, you will have problems.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a multi-select and you need to remove the `selected` from all rows, you can use the following:

```
 $("#mySelect option:selected").each(function () {
               $(this).removeAttr('selected'); 
               });
```

The first clause fetches all of the selected options, while the `each` iterates through them, and the removeAttr eliminates the 'selected'.

Answer (score 0):

$('#mySelect').val('new value');
This automatically selects the  with that value.

But in the case of the value is not exists before in select options
no value will be selected,
So make sure the value already exists in select options.